# MySQL - Concatenating Fields to Appended Field

Tags: mysql, append, concatenation

Simple one really - or should be.

I have multiple fields that I want to condense and append to one longtext field.

I'm guessing that this is a concat function but I don't know how to append concatenated values to a field in the same row with an existing value.

Is there a MySQL statement that will do the trick or will I have to run a looping php script?

Example...

```
ID | NAME | POSITION | NOTES
1 | Richard | Programmer | Not paid enough
2 | David | Manager | Lazy
3 | Hilary | Personnel Manager | Doesn't care
```

Ultimately, I want to delete the NAME and POSITION fields but I want to store those values beforehand so I want to concatenate " - ".NAME." - ".POSITION and append it to NOTES without losing any data from that field so the result would be...

```
ID | NAME | POSITION | NOTES
1 | Richard | Programmer | Not paid enough - Richard - Programmer
2 | David | Manager | Lazy - David - Manager
3 | Hilary | Personnel Manager | Doesn't care - Hilary - Personnel Manager
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: The `CONCAT` function should be able to do this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: Can you illustrate your problem by adding sample data and expected result as text to the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you.  I know how to concat but that in itself doesn't give me the whole solution unforuntately.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have now added an example which should be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The `CONCAT` function can easily handle this in MySQL:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    NAME,
    POSITION,
    CONCAT(NOTES, ' - ', NAME, ' - ', POSITION) AS NOTES
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks but again, this is just a concat select function.  It doesn't append anything which is the critical part of my request.

Comment: @RichardOwens Then maybe do an update as PSalmon suggets.  I vote against persisting the new  column as it duplicates information.

Comment: I understand it creates duplicates but I want to delete these fields when theyve all concatenated.  The @PSalmon solution is pretty much what I'm looking for but thank you again for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(ID int, NAME varchar(20), POSition varchar(20),NOTES varchar(500));
insert into t values
(1 , 'Richard' , 'Programmer' ,      'Not paid enough'),
(2 , 'David'   , 'Manager'    ,      'Lazy'),
(3 , 'Hilary'  , 'Personnel Manager','Doesnt care');

update t
set notes =
    CONCAT(NOTES, ' - ', NAME, ' - ', POSITION) 
where 1 = 1;

select * from t;

+------+---------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
| ID   | NAME    | POSition          | NOTES                                    |
+------+---------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
|    1 | Richard | Programmer        | Not paid enough - Richard - Programmer   |
|    2 | David   | Manager           | Lazy - David - Manager                   |
|    3 | Hilary  | Personnel Manager | Doesnt care - Hilary - Personnel Manager |
+------+---------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Ultimately, I want to delete the NAME and POSITION fields* are you sure you want to do that? getting the bits out again is a pain.

If any of the elements is null concat will return null if an element is not guaranteed to have a value then an ifnull test is necessary

```
    update t
    set notes =
        CONCAT(IFNULL(NOTES,''), ' - ', IFNULL(NAME,''), ' - ', IFNULL(POSITION,'')) 
    where 1 = 1;

drop table if exists t;
create table t(ID int, NAME varchar(20), POSition varchar(20),NOTES varchar(500));
insert into t values
(1 , 'Richard' , 'Programmer' ,      'Not paid enough'),
(2 , 'David'   , 'Manager'    ,      'Lazy'),
(3 , 'Hilary'  , 'Personnel Manager','Doesnt care'),
(4 , 'HILARY'  , NULL,'DOES NOW') ;

update t
set notes =
    CONCAT(IFNULL(NOTES,''), ' - ', IFNULL(NAME,''), ' - ', IFNULL(POSITION,'')) 
where 1 = 1;

+------+---------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
| ID   | NAME    | POSition          | NOTES                                    |
+------+---------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
|    1 | Richard | Programmer        | Not paid enough - Richard - Programmer   |
|    2 | David   | Manager           | Lazy - David - Manager                   |
|    3 | Hilary  | Personnel Manager | Doesnt care - Hilary - Personnel Manager |
|    4 | HILARY  | NULL              | DOES NOW - HILARY -                      |
+------+---------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Interestingly, this seems to work in isolation where all fields are not NULL.  If either Foo or Bar are NULL, then NOTES doesn't update with either Foo or Bar!  I am applying this over 3 concatenated fields and it is common to have at least one as NULL which returns no update.

And, yes, I am sure I want to do this - perhaps using a unique separator in case I need to explode as a backup.

Comment: CORRECTION, IT HAS JUST UPDATED THE NOTES FIELD FOR THE ENTIRE DATABASE WITH A NULL VALUE - EFFECTIVELY DELETING ALL RECORD NOTES... OOPS!!